# Deletes are not propagated in associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. For ex: a, b, c

```
a:
has_many: bs

b:
belongs_to: a
belongs_to: c

c:
has_many: bs
```

so, now the issue is when I delete a record in `c` which is associated with `b`, the change is reflected in `b` but not in `a`.

Expected change is `a.b.c` value is null as `c` is deleted. But it is not null and still showing the value as earlier.

When I manually update the particular record in b and check the value of `a.b.c`, then it is null.

So, is there any solution to fix this?
something like reload or refresh?

Thanks.

PS: I am using activescaffolding to perform actions.

**SOLUTION**:

```
model c: 
has_many: bs, :dependent => :nullify
```

Above line fixed my issue. :D

Comment: has_many: bs ,  dependent: :destroy

Comment: dependent: destroy - doesn't this delete the whole record instead of nullifying the value?

Comment: consider polymorphism - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: "something like reload or refresh?" - yes. `a.b.reload`

Comment: @serigo, I can run that command in the rails console. But is there a way to do it through the model everytime delete happens?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `has_many` association, you don't own the foreign key, so you need to tell the other side of the association to destroy itself.

You can do this with the `dependent: destroy` qualifier on your `has_many` associations. For example, if you have:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

then you can do

```
author.destroy
```

and all the `Articles` with `author`'s `author_id` will be destroyed.

Comment: Hi, I don't have issue with the first level of association.
The issue is: when an Author is deleted, Article is updated successfully.
Let's suppose, that article belongs_to :group.

Author in the Article of that group is not nullifying.

Answer (score 0):

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy 
end
```

comment.rb

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :post
 end
```

When you destroy post it destroy comment related to same post.

```
post.destroy
```